# Parenting views in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Currently i am trying to implement the following. While making a compass, i would like to draw arrows(circles) at set locations and rotate around my view to display on compass.

I can use storyboard to create Imageviews and the like and parent them with one another.

I am trying to now do this programming code, as that when a new location is received by program it can display the new point on compass.
I have already worked out code to rotate around

Ideally my flow of code should be as follows:

For i = 1 to 5;

1. Draw empty square view[i]
2. Draw Circle and position within square[i] at co-ordinate (x,y)    (pretty much at the north point of compass)
3. Parent circle to Square
4. Rotate square[i] to x degrees.
5. Next i

My question is how do i programmatically draw these views and then how do i parent the views. Such that i can rotate one with the other at a fixed point.

Thanks.

Comment: And what have you done so far ?

Comment: What do you mean by empty square view ?

Comment: So far i have implemented the compass through storyboards. The compass points to a location which is shown by a circular image of location(this is my arrow pointer). The circle is placed at north point, and parented to an empty square the exact size of compass circle.That square is then rotated to the correct bearing(hence location circle moves around a circular path) by rotating the square.

Empty square view is just an empty UIview/Imageview. Its more a placeholder used to rotate a  circle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not exact answer, but it may help you.just play with value of i(loop index)

```
-(void) rotateOn360Degree
 {
    int x,y;

    double radious=30;
    for(int i=1;i<=360;i++)
    {
          x = radious* cos((i * 3.14) / 180));
         y =  radious* sin((i * 3.14) / 180));
         UIView *tmpView = [[UIView alloc] init];
         [tmpView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]]; 
        [tmpView.layer setCornerRadius:5];
         tmpView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,  10, 10);
        [self.view addSubview:tmpView];
    }
  }
```

Comment: If i'm understanding this correctly, what this does is for each degree it makes a circle size radius(10)?

Comment: remove loop from code, and pass static value for i, like 30, 50,70,90

Comment: Thanks Mate. So i pretty much can use this to rotate my created subview, without creating a rectangle. Cheers.

Comment: don't forget to accept my answer(click green tick mark at my answer) or increase vote count